# [skeleton.launch] is neither a launch file in package [skeleton_markers] nor is [skeleton_markers] a launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i had this strange error. a few days ago, i've succeed `catkin_make` and `roslaunch skeleton_markers skeleton.launch` . so the program successfully running. But, because of i have some error code for my other package on my workspace, someone said that i have to delete the 'build' folder in my workspace and re build my package, but i accidentally delete (with `SHIFT+DEL`) my **install** folder (which is source of my **install/setup.bash**). --this is my stupid accident--
after that, i remake my install folder by `catkin_make install` in my workspace folder with source in my devel/setup.bash and rebuild with `catkin_make`, and change again my source to **install/setup.bash**, and rebuild again with `catkin_make`.

but still, the result is said that  :

```
 [skeleton.launch] is neither a launch file in package [skeleton_markers] nor is [skeleton_markers] a launch file
```

i've done re-package my package folder by `catkin_create-pkg`, but the result still same. i don't know anymore what i have to do with this. please help me :"(

oh, and it's not only that package which have error, but i think all my package inside my workspace can't be launched :(
i can find my rospackage with `rospack find <package>`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220832/%5Bskeleton.launch%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-%5Bskeleton_markers%5D-nor-is-%5Bskeleton_markers%5D-a-launch-file/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the best way you should follow is backing up your packages, deleting your catkin workspace and creating your workspace again with `catkin_init_workspace` . After you can put your packages back and run `catkin_make`. Do not forget to source your `devel/setup.bash` in your `.bashrc` file or running `source /home/<username>/<catkin_ws>/devel/setup.bash` in your terminal.

**UPDATE**

In your .bashrc, you should have:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/ros/devel/setup.bash
```

Also, seems like your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable is outdated. In your terminal, can you run;

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/adelleodel/ros/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-11-12**:
I've try it for devel/setup.bash before.. and i hv problem with openni library (problem when `catkin_make`) that can't find openni package though the file was there, and the problem solved by changing my source to install/setup.bash (i don't know why). But i'll try again with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH update

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-11-12**:
Yeah, i succesfully can launch one of my packages. But, i still have another packages that still stuck in my old workspace path. It still respond same error, and when i `rospack find package`, it said that `/home/adelleodel/rosadel/install/share/my_package` what to do?

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-11-12**:
Ahhh it seems that i haven't move that package /lol
Thankyou so much for your help Akif!!! ^^

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-12**:
I'm glad you figured it out!

**Comment by [Alan8](https://answers.ros.org/users/43678/alan8/) on 2019-06-28**:
I get this error all the time!  What a flaky system!  Sourcing setup.bash fixes it SOMETIMES.  It's not working now.